# Datepicker formatting correctly

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

ok so i have a datepicker and the initial state is like this
Jul. 21, 2010 but when i pick a date i get this format 07/21/2010 how do i get it so when i select the date from the datepicker it goes back to this format Jul. 21, 2010

here is my code

```
<p class="left search_date"><%= text_field_tag "tee_date", @date.strftime('%b. %d, %Y'), :size => 9 if @date %><span class="search_tip">(Change)</span></p>                                                          

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tee_date").datepicker();
    var tee_date = $("#tee_date").datepicker({ maxDate: '+1y', minDate: new Date() });
    $(".search_tip").click(function(){
        tee_date.datepicker("show");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't really a rails question... This belongs in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the parameter **dateFormat: 'M d,yy'** when you call the datepicker function ..

```
var tee_date = $("#tee_date").datepicker({ maxDate: '+1y', minDate: new Date(), dateFormat: 'M d,yy' });
```